# Images not rendered in sharepoint site

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, publishing-site

We have a publishing site deployed to Internet. When we browser this site with machine name locally, we encountered below problems:

1. There are no images appearing in site and display cross 'X', even in Site Settings.
2. Also when we open any document library, pages library, we cannot see any images

[image: screenshot]

Comment: its a problem occurring only when you browse your site with machine name? or this problem also exist with other site mapped URL?

Comment: with machine name and hostname also , in AAM default zone is Hostname http //www.mysite com for example and in Intranet zone machine name

Comment: can you see the images with any admin accounts, like System Account/Site Collection Admin/Farm Admin? with what accounts you cannot see these images?

Comment: even with spfarm account i logged in , can not view the images

Comment: Browse site in IE and then open the Image library using Explorer, or map the Library to drive and check if the images still exist there

Comment: Hi i went to sitesettings>object cache settings and did object cache flush even i have the same problem , i did not see any images in site settings page,viewall site content page

Comment: i checked all images are exists in this path  C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\IMAGES in this path

Comment: even i restart wfe servers i have same issue, please can any one post how to solve this ?

Comment: Inspect the image and see which URL is configured. Is it valid? Use the F12 console to check for related errors when the page loads.